# Why is BioShock still available for PS Plus download?

Tags: ps3, playstation-plus

I'm still new to this PS Plus thing, but I think I know the basics: every month you get new games for the PS3, PS4, Vita.

In January, BioShock was available for download and strangely enough, it's April and I can still download that game, same as Uncharted. In the games preview, same thing happens for Brothers: A Tale of Two Sons - it's not in this month rotation, yet I can still download it.

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Did you already claim them? If you claim the download in a prior month, you get to keep it "forever" as long as your PS+ subscription is active

Comment: No i didn't claim Bioshock or Brother's , but for some reason i still get the option to download them but they are not in the rotation, can u explain that?

Answer (score 2):

You're right that new games are added to the "Instant Game Collection" each month, but they don't all disappear again at the same time. Some games only stay for the month, but others stay longer.

For example, in October 2013 in Europe, Metal Gear Rising and Remember Me were both added at the 23rd, but Metal Gear Rising disappeared in November and Remember Me stayed until the end of January 2014.

In your case, Brothers was added in March and Bioshock Infinite in January, but they still haven't been removed, while other games like Mero: Last Light or Tomb Raider, that were released around the same time are not available anymore.

Release dates and games differ between North America and the rest of the world. On wikipedia you can find a list of all games that have been released in the "Instant Game Collection", and when they were added and removed, for [North America](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Instant_Game_Collection_games_%28North_America%29) and [the PAL region](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Instant_Game_Collection_games_%28PAL_region%29).

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this to me ' i wub you :3

Comment: @user74671 In that case you should [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/215106)

Comment: FWIW, a few days ago (May 29th, 2014), [Sony](http://blog.us.playstation.com/2014/05/29/playstation-plus-2-titles-per-month-for-ps4-ps3-ps-vita/) announced changes to PSN+ where free titles will be available for a month, then return to for-pay status. Older free games will also be getting reverted to for-pay only status as well, so if you see something up there still free, get it now.